# Can Includes for Navigation Properties be Nested in Web API using EF6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

From my `Web API` service using a generic-repository/uow pattern with `EF6`, I need to return nested navigation properties.  Model A has a Model B and Model B has a Model C and so on.  Something like this:

```
public class A
    {
        public int SomeID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
    }    
public class B
    {
        public int SomeID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
    }
```

I can get the Bs in A, but the Cs in B are null.  This is how I'm doing it:

```
// GENERIC REPOSITORY
public IQueryable<TEntity> Get(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;
            if (includes != null)
            {
                foreach (var include in includes)
                    query = query.Include(include);
            }
            return query;
        }
//  FROM THE "A" CONTROLLER
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            var results = _unitOfWork.A_Repository.Get(s => s.Bs);
            if (results == null)
            {
                response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            else
            {
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, results);
            }
            return response;
        }
```

I don't see how I can pass additional lambdas from the A controller to get the Cs in B loaded.  I can see how to do this without using a generic repository.  I'm open to using OData too, but can't figure out how to do it using this pattern in Web API

I also tried using the DbContext approach and failed:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
        public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<C> Cs { get; set; }

        public MyContext()
            : base("MyDBContext")
        {
        }    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<B>().HasRequired(i => i.C);
            Bs.Include(i => i.C);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do this using single `Include` call.

```
_context.A_Repository // where to get from
    .Include(a => a.Bs.Select(b => b.Cs.Ds.Es)) // what to include
    .Where(a => a.IsCool == true) // how to filter
    .ToList(); // materialize result
```

[See remarks of EntityFramework documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Comment: This works.  In my example, it needs to be coded from the unit-of-work(_unitOfWork) not the context. Thanks.